# Most efficient way to seek around in a large file

Tags: performance, haskell, io

What's the most efficient way to process really large binary files in Haskell?

The standard answer is to read the entire file as a lazy ByteString and then use something like the Binary packet to write a parser over it. There are a couple of problems with that...

First, libraries like Binary don't really handle parse failure, and I'm explicitly *expecting* parsing to fail sometimes.

Second, I'm not parsing the entire file contents. I'm going to be skipping over large chunks of it. And reading gigabytes of data from disk into RAM only to have the garbage collector throw it away again seems rather unperformant.

Related to that, I need to be able to tell if the skip I want to perform will take me off the end of the file or not (and error out if it does).

I may also need to seek *backwards*, or maybe to a specific byte offset within the file, which does not appear to be well-supported by a lazy ByteString approach. (There's a severe danger of ending up holding the entire file in RAM.)

The alternative, of course, is to read individual bytes one by one, interleaved with `hSeek` commands. But now the problem is, how efficient is reading a file one byte at a time? That sounds like it could *also* be quite slow. I'm not sure is `hSetBuffering` has an effect on this. (?)

Then of course there's `mmap`. But that seems to freak out the virtual memory system if used on large files. (Which is odd, considering that's the entire purpose for it existing...)

What do we think, folks? What's the best way to approach this, in terms of I/O performance and code maintainability?

Comment: What about `hGetBuf`, `hGetBufNonBlocking` and `hGetSome`? You can read in larger thunks than single bytes.

Comment: Use [a mmap'd bytestring](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring-mmap/0.2.2/doc/html/System-IO-Posix-MMap-Lazy.html)? Indexing then only loads the required blocks from memory.

Comment: I wander how all this interacts with `hSetBuffering`?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue when working on pdf parser. Initially I used `iteratee` package (it [supports random access](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/iteratee/0.8.9.4/doc/html/Data-Iteratee-Iteratee.html#v%3aseek)). AFAIK it is the only IO library with random IO support.

My [current approach](https://github.com/Yuras/pdf-toolbox/blob/master/core/lib/Pdf/Toolbox/Core/IO/RIS.hs) is based on `io-streams` package. I found it more convenience. Performance is goods enough, `attoparsec` integration out of the box, a lot of combinators included.

Here is a basic example how to use `iteratee` for random IO:

```
shum@shum-laptop:/tmp/shum$ cat test.hs 

import qualified  Data.Iteratee as I
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.Iteratee as I
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.Char8 as P
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import System.Environment

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [file] <- getArgs
  flip I.fileDriverRandom file $ do
    I.seek 20
    num1 <- I.parserToIteratee P.number
    liftIO $ print num1
    I.seek 10
    num2 <- I.parserToIteratee P.number
    liftIO $ print num2
shum@shum-laptop:/tmp/shum$ cat in.data 
111111111
222222222
333333333
shum@shum-laptop:/tmp/shum$ runhaskell test.hs in.data 
333333333
222222222
shum@shum-laptop:/tmp/shum$
```

Comment: I'm not really familiar with iteratee technology. I gather there's a lot of interest in it lately, and perhaps it's a good way to solve my problem, but the `iteratee` package itself is a bit too sparse on documentation for me to figure this out.

Comment: I added an example. It is pretty basic, but should give the idea.